# ¿duplicar un Jpanel?

Tags: java-swing

Me encuentro realizando una aplicación de escritorio en java, actualmente tengo una plantilla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo en una Bd la tabla de documentos y usuarios , un usuario tiene muchos documentos,lo que quiero realizar con los datos de la Bd ,reemplazar los datos que esta en la plantilla por datos de la Bd , y para eso debo "multiplicar" las "cartas" que tengo en la plantilla.

[![Lo que estaba pensando realizar , pero al correr la aplicación no me genera mas objetos][2]][2]

estaba pensando realizar al iniciar la aplicación crear un for que recorra todos los componentes.de ahi preguntar si es Jpanel y extraer sus elementos, y ai todo ese rollo, pero al correr la aplicacion no me crea mas objetos.

```
for (Component panel : this.jPanelAll_documentos.getComponents()) {
        if (panel instanceof JPanel) {
            JPanel instancia_panel = new JPanel(((JPanel) panel).getLayout());
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Dante, puedes explicar mejor tu problema? Añade también lo que has intentado y el porqué no te funcionó: errores, resultado no esperado, .. ? Un saludo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon toda esa descripción en ella para que podamos leer con claridad y entender. Saludos